# Memory map while developing C application with Eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse

Just for educational purpose I have written C code that gets out of array bound:

```
int main( int argc, char ** argv ) {

    char *cp = "dabsf";
    cp=cp+10;
    printf("%c",*cp);
    return 0;
}
```

I have letter `n` in output.

Is it possible somehow to see whole memory map and see what bytes are near `cp` array and find where is `n`?

I'm using `MinGW` compiler.

Comment: You could always view memory contents in a debugger. If you want to do it in code, it depends on what platform (I'm assuming Windows?)

Comment: you get `n` each time you run this program?

Comment: Portably, no. Accessing memory out of bounds of an array is *undefined behavior* and can cause the program to behave unpredictably, including printing `n`, printing nothing at all, crashing, going into an infinite loop, etc.

Answer (score 0):

To print the memory map of 10 positions from cp:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
int i;
char *cp = "dabsf";
printf("Address of 1st element of cp %p\n", cp);

for(i=1;i<=10;i++)
{
    printf("Address of %c is %p\n",*(cp+i), cp+i); // cp+i is the same as &(*(cp+i))
}
return 0;
```

}

To get the address of any element after the array:

```
cp = cp + 8;
printf("Element at cp+8 is %c\n", *cp);
printf("Address of cp+8 is %p\n", cp);
```

Note: the output of the code just above may change in successive runs of the code.

Comment: Did you add 8 to `cp` because characters are normally bytes? Not only is that not standard but with pointers adding 1 steps the address forward by the `sizeof` of the type being pointed to. This will give you the 9th element of `cp`, not the 2nd. Also `&(*cp)` is redundant, just put `cp` in there.

Comment: *(cp+1) gives the second element of cp which is 'a' and &(*(cp+i)) gives its address. I had run it in eclipse. cp is a char pointer, the     sizeof char is 1 bytes in gcc Ubuntu. I added 8 to cp to point to the 9th element that is outside the array, and printed its address. The questioner wanted to find where is 'n'.

Comment: Ah I didn't get that you were trying to get the 9th element at the end there. Still `&(*(cp + i))` is equivalent to `cp + i`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code to print memory out, you can use it to print memory around after any pointer you want (trying to print too much might give you an access violation, especially trying addresses before your first variable):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printMemory(void *address, int rows, int cols) {
    for(int r = 0, c; r < rows; ++r) {
        c = 0;
        printf("%8p ", (void *)(((unsigned int*)address) + (r*cols + c)));
        for(; c < cols; ++c) {
            printf("0x%08x ", *(((unsigned int *)address) + (r*cols + c)));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }   
}

int main(void) {
    char *test = "Hello World!";
    unsigned int value1 = 0xABABABAB;
    unsigned int value2 = 0xDEADBEEF;
    unsigned int value3 = 0xCAFEBABE;

    printf("%s, %d, %d, %d\n", test, value1, value2, value3);

    printMemory(test, 4, 2);
    printf("\n");
    printMemory(&value1, 1, 3);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is (in my case the string was stored in a different place than the integers):

```
Hello World!, -1414812757, -559038737, -889275714
0x80486ad 0x6c6c6548 0x6f57206f 
0x80486b5 0x21646c72 0x2c732500 
0x80486bd 0x2c642520 0x2c642520 
0x80486c5 0x0a642520 0x01000000 

0xbf8aab50 0xabababab 0xcafebabe 0xdeadbeef
```

Also this works for debugging, but do not do this in real code, accessing memory addresses that aren't for your variables is undefined behavior.